# Need help in deriving mathematical formula

Tags: linear-algebra

I need a mathematical formula that would give me the specified result for given input x (x is always an integer)

```
1<=x<=14 ==>16
15<=x<=30 ==>32
31<=x<=46 ==>48
```

I was able to derive the below formula which gives correct result when used in a C program with x as integer but finding little difficult to derive a mathematical formula with basic arithmetic operations

```
( ( ( (x+1)/16 )*16 )+ 16)
```

Thanks
Zulfi

Comment: If you'll use it in a C program, what's wrong with an "if" statement?

Comment: You pretty much have it. Integer division in a programming language removes the decimal, which is equal to the floor operation. So you have $\lfloor\frac{x+17}{16}\rfloor\cdot16$, which is equal to what you wrote, just a bit different.

Comment: Sorry for missing this piece, I am not going to use it in C program instead I need an algebraic formula. The C style expression was only for depicting.